# JBOSS - Remote EJB lookup

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jndi

I have this Ear ("Application.ear"):

```
Application.ear;
|__ejbProj.jar;
|  |___source;
|      |___bean;
|      |   |___LocalHelloWorld.class;
|      |   |___RemoteHelloWorld.class;
|      |
|      |___bean_interface;
|          |___HelloWorldInterface.class;
|
|__WEB.jar;
.
.
.
```

My WEB.jar contains a servlet that tries to lookup my remote ejb.

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            context = new VelocityContext();
            final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
            jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");

            InitialContext initialContext;
            String errorStatus="Undefined";
        try {

            initialContext = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
            HelloWorldInterface remoteEjb=(HelloWorldInterface) initialContext.lookup("ejb:/Application/ejbProj/RemoteHelloWorld!source.bean_interface.HelloWorldInterface");           

            if (remoteEjb!=null) {

                errorStatus=remoteEjb.printMessage();
            }
            else {

                errorStatus="Error";
            }
        } catch (NamingException e) {

            errorStatus="NamingException: "+e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error that i get:

> EJBCLIENT000024: Not able to find EJB matching "StatelessEJBLocator
>   for "/Application/RemoteHelloWorld/ejbProj", view is interface
>   source.bean_interface.HelloWorldInterface, affinity is None"

This is my interface:

```
public interface HelloWorldInterface {

    public String printMessage();

}
```

This is my RemoteBean:

```
@Remote
@Stateless
public class RemoteHelloWorld implements HelloWorldInterface{

    @Override
    public String printMessage() {

        return "This is a remote EJB called \"RemoteHelloWorld\"";
    }

}
```

Can you help me with this? Thanks

Comment: What version of JBoss are you using?

Comment: the version is: 7.1.0.Beta1

Comment: Why are you trying to lookup a remote EJB reference into a co-located servlet when you could just @EJB inject it instead?

Comment: For educational purposes